# How to pass values to mex files

Tags: matlab, mex

Hi I want to send a value from my matlab to my mex function. The value is generally about 10 digits long and i have used unsigned long long data type.

But i have difficulty accessing it from the mexfile. 
mxGetPr returns double type, so is there some type conversion i have to do?

Comment: it's a floating point value so store it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I just encountered this.  You shouldn't use `mxGetPr` anymore in general.  The better way to do it is to first check the type like this:

```
if(!mxIsClass(prhs[0],"double"))
{
    mexErrMsgTxt("Data must be of type double!!!\n");
}
```

Then access the data through `(double *)mxGetData(prhs[0])` or in your case `(unsigned long long int*)mxGetData(prhs[0])`

You can look up `mxIsClass` and `mxGetData` for more info.

Edit:  [Also here's a list of the different types for `mxIsClass`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mxisclass.html)